# How can I load a console after killing xserver?

Tags: xorg, raspberry-pi, networkmanager, console

I'm attempting to build a kiosk, and using Xorg to load Chromium in kiosk mode (Raspberry OS). I am a web developer, but a bit of a novice with this level of linux work.

To future proof this, I want to find a graceful way of allowing a user to connect to a wi-fi network if connection is lost. I haven't found any common solutions to this, so am trying to implement something which in my head feel like it could work.

So I Network Manager installed, and have a cron job checking for an active internet connection, and if one isn't detected, it exits Xorg.

My plan is then to display Network Manager using nmtui which will allow the user to select a new network.

The problem I have is that once I've killed Xorg, I have no console to display Network Manager.

Is there anyway to launch a console after killing Xorg, allowing me to then display Network Manager?

Comment: hm, no offense, but that sounds not very user-friendly. Say, you're browsing some information, watching some video, *something* interrupts the wifi connection **BAM** your browser with all that you loved gets killed.

Comment: I think a small systray window that only shows `nm-applet` would probably be both nicer and much easier to set up?

Comment: You are right about the user experience, but was just trying to achieve something within my ability. It's  not expected for the network to go down, it's more of a back up should it get moved to a different location so someone can set it up easily without actually having access to anything else on the machine.

So I guess I should try to see if I can launch nm-applet instead. If that can pop up in kiosk mode without closing the browser, that would be a great solution - so thanks for that really helpful pointer.

Comment: Why are you killing Xorg?

Comment: Im looking for a way to pop up some way of allowing a user to connect to a wifi network of the internet connection is locked. The only way I could think of doing it was by closing Xorg and throwing something up in the console. If there’s a way of opening  something to open in Xorg that would be better.

Comment: I anyone's interested, I got around the issue by doing the internet connectivity check only on boot. Only if it fails, a timeout question is launched allowing the user to load nmtui to configure the network. If there is no user input in 10 secs the device continues to boot.

The check is merely there as a fallback to allow a user (admin) configuration through a 'diagnostic port' (USB keyboard)  if something unforeseen happens (location moved maybe, which requires it to be unplugged anyway). This suits my requirements perfectly, as may never get used after initial setup.